# Use/Display specific ArrayList String for ListView

Tags: android, arrays, listview, arraylist

I'm having trouble displaying the right String from an ArrayList in my ListView.

My Array (m_aDataList) looks like this:

```
    m_aDataList {ArrayList}
      {...}0
         m_cText = "R;21;9;River Street 2;12154;;1;.......
         m_cTimeStamp = 1556553367492
         m_nID = 7
         m_nStatus = 0
         m_nType = 10002
       {...}1
....
```

This is how I'm currently trying to Display the ArrayList in my ListView:

```
ArrayAdapter<Message> tuAdapter;
        MessageManager tu = new MessageManager();
        ArrayList<Message> list = tu.getMessageData();
        tuAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Message>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
        lvOrders.setAdapter(tuAdapter);
```

It *technically* works and adds something like this to my ListView:

```
de.telematik.testapp.entities.Message@232d9c76
```

But what I'm trying to do is, only show Messages where m_nType == 10002 and Display them like this in my ListView:

```
Order: 12154 (order number from m_cText)
```

Checking weither or not m_nType is = 10002 or 10000 shouldn't be the problem. But how do I get the order number out of the String m_cText and then display it in my ListView?

In any case, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a basic default list adapter, but you are passing it an array of objects (Message).  In order to control what displays in the list, you will need to create your own custom adapter class, that extends (probably base adapter) one of the standard adapter classes.  You will call it similarly to the way you pass your list to your simple list adapter.  Here is a sample custom list adapter:

```
ClaimListAdapter.java

            package com.mycompany.myapp.adapter;

            import java.text.ParseException;
            import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
            import java.util.ArrayList;
            import java.util.Date;

            import com.mycompany.myapp.R;
            import com.mycompany.myapp.ClaimListFragment;
            import com.mycompany.myapp.model.ClaimItem;

            import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
            import android.app.Activity;
            import android.content.Context;
            import android.view.LayoutInflater;
            import android.view.View;
            import android.view.ViewGroup;
            import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
            import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
            import android.widget.Button;
            import android.widget.TextView;


            public class ClaimListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

                private Context context;
                private ArrayList<ClaimItem> claimItems;
                ClaimListFragment fragment;

                public ClaimListAdapter(ClaimListFragment fragment, Context context, ArrayList<ClaimItem> claimItems){
                    this.context = context;
                    this.claimItems = claimItems;
                    this.fragment = fragment;
                }

                @Override
                public int getCount() {
                    return claimItems.size();
                }

                @Override
                public Object getItem(int position) {       
                    return claimItems.get(position);
                }

                @Override
                public long getItemId(int position) {
                    return position;
                }

                @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
                @Override
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                // This method gets called for every item in the list when it is about to be displayed in the list

                    // This helps you get a reference to the layout of the list item
                    if (convertView == null) {
                        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                                context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.claim_list_item, null);
                    }

                    // If you have a button that you want to perform some function, such as delete, and then call
                    // a method back in the parent to update the items in the array, this is one way to do it
                    Button btnDelete = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.claim_delete_in_list);
                    // Save the position of the item in the list, so, you know which item was clicked
                    btnDelete.setTag(position);

                    btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Integer position = (Integer)v.getTag();
                            // Call this method which is back in the parent, which in this case is a fragment, but could be an Activity
                            fragment.deleteItemList(position);
                        }
                    });

                    btnDelete.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    // Here you get a reference to the various TextViews in your layout 
                    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.claim_title);
                    TextView txtStatus = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.claim_status);
                    TextView txtDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.claim_date);
                    TextView txtDistance = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.claim_distance);
                    TextView txtAmount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.claim_amount);

                    // Here you get the various strings out of your object for display
                    String claim_title = claimItems.get(position).getDocumentID();

                    if (claim_title == null) {
                        claim_title = "";
                    }


                    String claim_status = claimItems.get(position).getClaimStatus();

                    String claim_date = claimItems.get(position).getClaimDate();

                    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
                    Date date = null;

                    try {
                        date = (Date) dateFormat.parse(claim_date);
                        dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yyyy"); 
                        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);
                        txtDate.setText(formattedDate);

                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                    double total_miles = claimItems.get(position).getTotalMiles();
                    double total_amount = claimItems.get(position).getTotalAmount();

                   // Here you set the values in the TextView for display
                    txtTitle.setText(claim_title);
                    txtStatus.setText(claim_status);

                    txtDistance.setText("" + total_miles + "mi");
                    txtAmount.setText("$" + total_amount);

                    return convertView;
                }

            }
```

Alternatively, you could create a string array containing only the order numbers from your array of messages, and pass that array to your list adapter instead of the array of messages.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try it out.